# Calling an external JS library function with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I am trying to load an external javascript file (http://turfjs.org/ a geospatial library I want to use within C#) and call a function (in my example turf.distance)
I am using the code below using Jint but I got an exception
Can you help me?
Thank you

```
String path = "turf.min.js";
String jsContent=File.ReadAllText(path);
try
{
    var script = new Engine()
    .Execute(jsContent)
    .GetValue("turf.distance");
    var result = script.Invoke(43.625, 3.61815, 43.6267, 3.60394);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // got an "Instance Error" (see image for details)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you were to inspect the exception, you would be able to solve your problem. Just a hint.

Comment: Please specify what errors you have been facing.

Comment: Yep, sorry, the exception is "InstanceError"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer has been given on github  (https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/) by the API creator who has been very efficient and available for solving this issue.